# Nested Geometric Functions in SLD in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, error, sld

I want to use nested geometric functions in SLD of GeoServer. For example I want to set some offset for certain type of polygons in my data. Then output of the offset geometric function needs to be given as input to another geometric function isometric to give required extrusion. I tried with following code.

the_geom
    0
    7
    
  the_geom
7

It gives no validation error but in layer preview, it is throwing the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find function isometric Unable to find function isometric

Is it possible to use nested function, or I am doing something wrong here?

Thanks in Advance.